How to disable cookie color changes in Chrome?
A recent update in Chrome introduced some mechanisms to show cookie value changes by red/green color highlighting.

I suffer from partial color blindness and the colors are very unclear to me, it's hard to distinguish them. Is there a way to completely disable this new feature and see the newest values?

Try using a custom devtools theme.
